# Why doesn't Nehushtan require its wielder to sing?

Tags: senki-zesshou-symphogear

When Chris purges Nehushtan and dons Ichii-bal during her fight against Hibiki in episode 7 of the first season, she complains about how she has to start singing now. And indeed, Ichii-bal, like Ame-no-Habakiri and Gungnir, generally requires the wielder to sing while transformed (because of, like, phonic gain, or something?).

However, neither Chris nor Finé sing when they wield Nehushtan (thereby depriving us of what would surely have been a glorious Sawashiro Miyuki battle song).

Why is that? Why doesn't Nehushtan require its wielder to sing?

Answer (score 1):

The answer turns out to be simple. There are two key facts here:

- Nehushtan is a complete relic. I'm not sure if this is mentioned in the show, but [it is mentioned in the season 1 keywords](http://www.symphogear.com/key12.html).
- According to Fujitaka in episode 3, a complete relic need only be activated by song a single time, with the caveat that the initial activation requires a significant amount of phonic gain. Thereafter, anybody can wield it at full power without needing to provide supplemental phonic gain in the form of song.

Nehushtan was activated in episode 1 by the phonic gain from the Zwei Wing concert, and was thus usable by anyone (including Chris and Finé) thereafter.

Comment: About point #1: It is mentioned in the 1st season that it is indeed a complete relic, in the first two episodes i think.  and it is a vital plot device: Finé stages the fight between Hibiki and Chris so the former can activate Durandal. Durandal remains active until the season finale. Also, any relic that is shown in full form can be assumed to be a complete relic, since the fragments are usually too small (the Gear pendants for example, are a mechanism **housing** a relic fragment.